# Why does the post-build event not cd?

Tags: visual-studio, cd, post-build-event

I put this on the post-build event:

```
cd
echo "hello" 
cd bin\Release
```

The result doesn't [cd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cd#:%7E:text=Displays%20the%20name%20of%20the%20current%20directory) to `bin\Release`:

```
1>D:\QC supplements\Code\LOS Installer
1>"hello"
```

Do you know why is that?
[image]

Comment: The project directory is the default directory while msbuild runs.  If you want to see the effect of cd bin\Release then put the cd command at the bottom.  Do note that bin\Release is not actually the build output directory for this project.

Comment: But I do put `cd bin\Release` at the bottom?

Comment: Sure, but you can't see its result since you run cd *before* changing the default directory.

Comment: I don't know what this question is building towards, but note that MSBuild shells out to run the Pre and Post-build events. Changing the directory only effects the spawned cmd shell. When the shell completes, the default directory will still be the project directory.

Comment: Do you mean that after the post-build event is done, it will cd back to the project directory?